# How to completion suggest Elasticsearch 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-5, search-suggestion, completion

I'm converting 1.7.5 => 5.4.2
But completion suggest output disappeared.

ex)

Es 1.7.5 Suggest Mapping

```
{   
    "test_suggest":[

      {
             "input": "bigbang",
             "payload": {
                 "type": "foo",
                 "id": "A",
                 "name": "BIGBANG"
             },
             "weight": 111,
             "output": "BIGBANG"

      },
      {

             "input": "빅뱅",
             "payload": {
                 "type": "foo",
                 "id": "B",
                 "name": "BIGBANG"
             },
             "weight": 111,
             "output": "빅뱅"

       },
       {

             "input": "qlrqod",
             "payload": {
                 "type": "foo",
                 "id": "B",
                 "name": "BIGBANG"
             },
             "weight": 111,
             "output": "빅뱅"
        }
    ]
 }
```

I went this

- search  -> result
- bigbang -> BIGBANG
- 빅뱅 -> 빅뱅
- qlrqod -> 빅뱅

5.4.2 suggest Mapping

```
{
    "test_suggest": [

           {
                "input": "bigbang",
                "weight": 111
            }
            ,
            {
                "input": "빅뱅",
                "weight": 111
            }
            ,
           {                
                "input": "qlrqod",
                "weight": 111,
             }
      ],
       "KEYWD" : "BIGBANG",
       "TYPE": "foo",
       "ID": "A"
 }
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch's completion suggester have been changed from 5.0.
The support for specifying output when indexing suggestion entries has been removed. Now suggestion result entry’s text is always the un-analyzed value of the suggestion’s input (same as not specifying output while indexing suggestions in pre-5.0 indices).
So you need to add `output` as a sibling field of `suggest` key in the body. 
 Here's how it should look like:

Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "<type>" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion"
                },
                "title" : {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace `<type>` with your index type.

Indexing:

```
/<index_name>/<type_name>

{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": ["bigbang"],
        "weight" : 1
    },
    "output": "BIGBANG"
}
```

Here, the field name `output` can be replaced by anything, it's just meta-data of your document.

Query:

```
/<index_name>/_search

{
    "suggest": {
        "show-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "bigbang",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.